# How to reconstruct objects from a dump file - Python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x, tkinter, pickle

I have created a paint application in python 3 by using tkinter. as a part of the application I am going to save the widget which contains shapes (oval, line , text,...). and reload them again.I am using pickle module and there is no problem with save, but when I reload it it just return me a list contain integers from 1 to N. that's it. no Objects, no shapes. How can I reconstruct my objects? 
here is my two function of save and load:

```
def save_project(self):
    output_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('Text', '*.txt')], title='save project as')
    try:
       with open(output_file, 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(self.stack, output)
        output.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
     self.log("Cancelled save or error in filename")

def load_project(self):
     load_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Text','*.txt')], title='Load Project')
     if not load_file: return
     pickled_file_object = open(load_file, "rb")
     pickled_file_object.seek(0)
     try:
        self.all_patterns = pickle.load(pickled_file_object)
     except EOFError:
      self.log("Error: End of file")
     pickled_file_object.close()

     try:
      # The problem is here:
      print(self.all_patterns)
      pprint.pprint(self.all_patterns)
     except:
      self.log("Error: Project can not be loaded")
```

the printed output is : 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23]

while the saved text file is :

8003 5d71 0028 4b01 4b02 4b03 4b04 4b05
4b06 4b07 4b08 4b09 4b0a 4b0b 4b0c 4b0d
4b0e 4b0f 4b10 4b11 4b12 4b14 4b15 4b16
4b17 652e

Comment: What did `self.stack` look like before you pickled it?

Comment: It's just a list which I add all objects to. Actually it works for an Undo function. I can delete the shapes based on that. so then it should be a way to create them again

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility within the canvas for saving and loading canvas objects. You will have to write code that iterates over the items, getting their coordinates and other attributes, and saving them in some format you can later parse. You will then have to write code that can read this data in and reconstruct all of the canvas objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My code is already 400 lines and if I want to do so it would be a huge mess I think. do you have any other solution? like if I change canvas to anything else?

Comment: You could create a custom canvas widget that has a method that, given the data you saved, draws it to the canvas. If number of lines really matter, use a different file and then import it.